# sqlite update in a loop take to long

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, loops

I am updating only 20 rows in a loop but the best performance I get is around 2.5 seconds for the 20 rows.
What can I do to make this simple update faster?

This is what Iv'e tried:

```
Dim connectionString As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\db.db3; Version=3;")
Dim connection = New SQLite.SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
connection.Open()
Dim com3 As New System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand(connection)
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
     com3.CommandText = "UPDATE Results SET LastScore=" & row.Item("position") & " WHERE TeamID='" & row.Item("teamid") & "'"
     com3.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
connection.Close()
```

AND

```
Dim connectionString As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\db.db3; Version=3;")
Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
    con.Open()
    Using c As New SQLiteCommand(con)
        c.CommandText = "UPDATE Results SET LastScore= @Pos WHERE TeamID = @ID"
        For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
            c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pos", row.Item("position"))
            c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Item("teamid"))
            c.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End Using
    con.Close()
End Using
```

Comment: The simplest way to speed up is to use transactions.

Comment: Thank you, that reduced it by 90%

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to muffi's answer this is now resolved. Add BeginTransaction()

```
Dim connectionString As New SQLite.SQLiteConnection("data source=" & Application.StartupPath & "\db.db3; Version=3;")
    Using con As New SQLiteConnection(connectionString)
        con.Open()
        Using t As SQLiteTransaction = con.BeginTransaction()
            Using c As New SQLiteCommand(con)
                c.CommandText = "UPDATE Results SET LastScore= @Pos WHERE TeamID = @ID"
                For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pos", row.Item("position"))
                    c.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", row.Item("teamid"))
                    c.ExecuteNonQuery()
                Next
            End Using
            t.Commit()
        End Using
        con.Close()
    End Using
```